# Can i work locally on VS Code with a virtual environment while ssh'ed to google colab

Tags: python, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I want to know if it's possible to work in a virtual environment while ssh'ed to google colab. I tried ssh'ing to google colab and did it but when I was going to code a .ipynb file I needed to select the kernel and when I tried selecting the one from my Conda Virtual Environment it did nothing. Wanted to know if it's possible or if I did something wrong. If you know some guide or video that teaches how to do this link it if possible, I already searched but found nothing. Thanks

After ssh'ing to google colab i tried inserting my conda env kernel in the VS Code kernel button but it did nothing so i couldn't run my .ipynb file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but if you want to work on a running Jupyter server using VScode, you need to connect to that remote jupyter server.
Here's the link to doc https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server

But also I'm not sure if collab supports plugins which vscode needs to install to run Jupyter remotely. But you should definitely try and install the Jupyter add-on first.